# WP плагин формы обратной связи с каптчей?

Tags: wordpress, cms

Подскажите хороший плагин для этой цели

Comment: Любой из оф каталога

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Contact Form 7](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/)

Проще некуда, но и возможностей достаточно. Капча есть. Потому и самый популярный, наверное.